# DataGridView in c#: combining Properties as Columns with elements of a List as Columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have been trying to wrap my mind around this problem for way too long... I am really out of ideas.

The explanation of what I need to achieve is pretty simple. This is my object, which contains a list:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> list { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I need the columns of the `DataGridView` to look like this:

```
[property1] | [property2] | [list_element1] | ... | [list_elementN]
```

The data binding should be as simple as possible (my real object has way more than two non-list properties).

I have even tried `Reflection` to create a dynamic object with `list_element1, ... , list_elementN` as properties. I kind of works, but there are certain issues with creating new rows of the `DataGridView` so I abandoned this path.

Any ideas of what could my best option be?

Comment: You can delete properties from your object and add them to  list. If it's impossible you can create `MyObjectViewModel` type with list of strings, where list[0] and list[1] will be property1 and property2. This my simple solution.

Comment: is the length of your list variable?

Comment: @stefankmitph : yes, it is variable.

Comment: is it possible that the first myObject has 3 list items and the second myObject has 6, while the third has only 1?

Comment: @stefankmitph : ok, now I see. Good point, I did not mention it in the post. Every `list`in every `myObject` will have the same length (with, of course, different values). So answering your question: no, `list` will not have a different `Count` in every instance of `myObject`. And all items will be aligned (`list[n]` represents the same concept across every difference instance of `myObject`. This is why they can be aligned in a table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way for you to do it... (and I want to make clear that my code indeed is very error prone but I just want to show that there's a silver lining, so please don't pin me down on this)

Assuming you have your datasource like this:

```
List<MyObject> dataSource = new List<MyObject>
{
    new MyObject
    {
        ID = 1,
        Name = "Row1",
        List = new List<string>() {"item1", "item2", "item3"}
    },
    new MyObject
    {
        ID = 2,
        Name = "Row2",
        List = new List<string>() {"item4", "item5", "item6"}
    },
    new MyObject
    {
        ID = 3,
        Name = "Row3",
        List = new List<string>() {"item7", "item8", "item9"}
    }
};
```

You can go for a dynamic datasource created out of your existing MyObject. (I took ExpandoObject so I can add properties to it dynamically)

```
List<dynamic> dynamicSource = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var data in dataSource)
{
    dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
    // assigning properties we already know
    o.ID = data.ID;
    o.Name = data.Name;

    int idx = 0; // just a counter. you could also do this with a for-loop of course
    foreach (var item in data.List)
    {
        var dict = o as IDictionary<string, Object>; // cast expando object just to get the properties as key and value pairs in a dictionary
        dict.Add("ItemNr" + idx, item);
        idx++;
    }
    dynamicSource.Add(o);
}
```

Now there's a little extension method I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573856/binding-a-gridview-to-a-dynamic-or-expandoobject-object) which becomes very handy at this point

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IEnumerable<dynamic> items)
    {
        var data = items.ToArray();
        if (data.Count() == 0) return null;

        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var key in ((IDictionary<string, object>)data[0]).Keys)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(key);
        }
        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(((IDictionary<string, object>)d).Values.ToArray());
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Now we can add the datasource to our DataGridView like this:

```
var dataTable = Extensions.ToDataTable(dynamicSource);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

It should be assigned correctly now.
What I've tested, adding rows shouldn't be a problem now.

If you want to get back your DataSource you have to take following little method:

```
private List<MyObject> ConvertBackToObject(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        // basically the same procedure as assigning

        List<MyObject> listMyDataSource = new List<MyObject>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            MyObject myObject = new MyObject
            {
                ID = Convert.ToInt16(row["ID"]),
                Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                List = new List<string>()
            };

            foreach (var column in dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(col => col.ColumnName.StartsWith("ItemNr")))
            {
                myObject.List.Add(row[column].ToString());
            }

            listMyDataSource.Add(myObject);
        }

        return listMyDataSource;
    }
```

which leads us to this (actually getting the datasource):

```
DataTable dataTable = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
// do some null checking here
List<MyObject> myObjects = ConvertBackToObject(dataTable);
```

This should give you the updated List of your MyObject (which you now can use for inserting data to the database).

Hope it is clear in some way and helped.

Comment: You are the man. Have already my upvote for the good idea and the thorough explanation. I will implement it as soon as I can, and you can be sure that I will come back to mark it as Answer once I've checked that everything works fine.

Comment: I translated it to vbnet and it works like a dream. Thank you so much, I would seriously buy you a beer if I could. BTW, I know you made just a silver lining, but I'll mention some minor improvements in case anyone is interested: The ExpandoObject can be defined as `IDictionary`. If we take take the properties of myObject dynamically with reflection (`propertyInfoArray = myObject.GetType().GetProperties()`) we can add them dynamically to the ExpandoObject (`o.Add(PropertyInfo.Name, value)`), while skipping the list (`if(PropertyInfo.Name = "List"){ continue; }`).

Comment: thanks mate! yes, doing it by reflection is another way. as said above, i had very little time to code it (but the goal was to provide a working example) and so i didn't want to bounce around with reflection. so... i'm glad it helped you along!