# How can I use a List<Dynamic> as with DataGridView.DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, expandoobject

I'm trying to bind a `List<dynamic>` to a DataGridView DataSource property.  While there are no errors when compiling there are no columns being displayed either.

If I pre-create the column I get the rows to display, but there's no data in them.

Simply put, how can I properly use a `List<dynamic>` object with my DataGridView?

Comment: More importantly, what does this Dynamic list look like? We can easily give you code to bind a list to DataGrid, but it doesn't guarantee that it will work in your scenario

Comment: @TheDanMan the Dynamic data list contains data from a SQL table, retrieved using dapper using the `Query` method. For the purposes of getting this to work I'm just using one field from the DB.

Comment: Show your code.  Ask specific and directed questions.

Comment: Detail how you pre-create the columns. IIRC you can't make databound columns without at least a template class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Dapper's dynamic query returns a collection of `ExpandoObject`s that lets you dynamically access properties such as `person.Name`, but the underlying objects doesn't actually have a `Name` property.  It uses run-time binding to extract the data from an internal key/value dictionary.  Since the default data binding for `DataGridView` uses reflection to get the properties of the objects, it does not find the columns returned from the query.

So you have a few options:

- Hydrate the result as a concrete type instead of `dynamic`
- Specify the columns you want to display in your `DataGridView` rather than using the default binding.
- Convert the dynamic result to a `DataTable` using something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298704/1081897).

Comment: Correct answer, with explanation and link to some code. Couldn't have asked for more, thank you.